# Aplicar una propiedad para discriminar una herencia en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Como puedo escoger un campo como `TipoOperacionId` para que sea discriminador, tengo el siguiente código.

```
public MovimientoMap()
    {
        ToTable("Movimientos");
        HasKey(c => c.MovimientoId);
        Property(c => c.MovimientoId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(c => c.MovimientoId).HasColumnOrder(0);

        HasRequired(c=>c.TipoOperacion).WithMany(c=>c.Movimientos).HasForeignKey(c=>c.TipoOperacionId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        Property(c => c.TipoOperacionId).HasColumnOrder(1);
        Property(c => c.FechaMovimiento).HasColumnOrder(2);

        Map<MovimientoVenta>(c => c.Requires("Type")
            .HasValue(1));

        Map<MovimientoCompra>(c => c.Requires("Type")
            .HasValue(2));
    }
```

[image: Movimientos UML]

Dase de Datos
[image: Diagrama Movimientos]

Comment: Puede ser así: `Map<MovimientoVenta>(c => c.Requires("TipoOperacionId")
                .HasValue(1));`

Comment: descriminador? no será "discriminador" ? a qué te refieres mi estimado?

Comment: @fredyfx, error de dedo, gracias por la observacion ya lo corregí.

Comment: @fredyfx Se puede crear un campo para descriminar la herencia, pero en mi caso puedo usar `TipoOperacionId` entonces en un comentario he puesto como creo que puede ser, ya lo he ejecutado en la DB y me parece que esta bien, no me ha creado un campo extra, es la primera vez que uso Herencia

Answer (score 0):

Es que no necesitas esconcer nada, la propiedad `TipooperacionId` en la clase `Movimientos` esta de mas, deberias quitarlo

Cuando mapeas solo indicas el nombre del campo en la tabla que actua de discriminador, no necesitas la propiedad en la clase.

Vuelve a revisar el articulo donde explico sobre el tema

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Herencia - Tabla por jerarquía - Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/08/entity-frameworkcode-first-herencia.html)

veras que en ningun momento defino la propiedad `Type` en las clases, pero si esta el campo en la tabla

Comment: Pero TipoOperacion esta relacionado con Movimientos(TipoOperacionId), al quitarle la relacion en la db ambas tablas quedan sin ralacion.

Comment: Agregue mas informacion a la pregunta

Comment: por eso te habia comentado en la otra pregunta que no necesitas ninguna tabla de TipoOperacion, los tipos quedan fijos en el codigo cuando mapeas cada herencia. La tabla TipoOperacion deberia eliminarla. Ademas de verdad un Estado en la tabla de tipos, eso es incorrecto